# how can we retrieve text response based on dynamic variables from resource files in spring-boot or java or python

Tags: java, python, spring-boot

I want to retrieve the label/text based on some parameter like below
resource file as below

```
greeting:
 channel: Facebook
       en:welcome to Facebook ...
       fr:bienvenue sur Facebook ...
       default: welcome to Facebook
 channel: slack
       en:welcome to slack.....
       fr:bienvenue sur slack ...
       default: welcome to slack
default:
       en:welcome
       fr:bienvenue
```

I want out as below:

```
gettext('greeting','Facebook','en') --> welcome to Facebook
gettext('greeting','Facebook') --> welcome to Facebook

gettext('greeting','fr')--> bienvenue
gettext('greeting')--> welcome
```

is there any lib available in spring boot or java or python to achieve above?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is close to `.yaml` type resource file and for that, I would suggest looking at this:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml

This is the closest to what you're describing. Other than this, I would suggest looking at implementations of yaml and see how you can modify them for your use case.

You can have a look at this code and see the YAML grammar for a pythonic way.

https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/master/lib/yaml/parser.py